# SSLSocket in Tomcat Spring

Tags: java, spring, sockets, ssl

I try to switch to SSL socket in my Spring Container:

```
SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket(socket, srvAddr, srvPort,true);
```

And get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

where socket is alredy opened normal socket (new Socket(srvAddr, srvPort);)

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tomas Narros gave you the reason. Here is a way of collecting the service certificate (chain) or even ignoring it entirely.

Create a TrustManager class with implements `javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager`

You will receive the server certificate chain in the `checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)`. In this method you can write simple code to save the received certificates. If you do not want to validate them, simply return without throwing an Exception.

To implement your TrustManager do do something like this

```
TrustManager[] myTrustManager = { new MyTrustManager() };
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

if (sendClientCerts) {   //send my certs for authentication to the server

    X509KeyManager kmsd = ...

    ctx.init(kmsd, myTrustManager, null);
} 
else {

    ctx.init(null, myTrustManager, null);
}

// Finally get a SSL Socket Factory and return it
SSLScketFactory ssf = ctx.getSocketFactory();

SSLSocket socket = ssf.createSocket(...);
```

Comment: None of this fiddling around with TrustManagers solves the *problem.* It just makes things more insecure, which is going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Maybe you should read twice: the OP problem is to recover the certificate; I gave a programmatic solution. Then implementing your own TrustManager you can actually better control security as you perform validation as you require.  I suspect you would not call this 'fiddling' if you had done low level SSL in Java before.

Comment: @BGR well you'd be wrong then, as I have done low level SSL in Java before, and I do call this 'fiddling'. 99% of the custom TrustManagers I have ever seen are not only radically insecure but also not even compliant with its own specification.

Comment: @Downvoter and EJP. The OP never asked for an opinion on what the security of his application should be and even less on what you think of programmers implementing TrustManagers. The OP was simply looking for practical solutions and is smart enough to understand what works and does not work for him. Actually expressing opinions, as explained in StackOverflow usage charter, is pointless: did you notice that the OP accepted this answer and how EJP's opinion on it, expressed in his first comment, thus proved to be totally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the server you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA.
You have to check if your truststore contains the certificates of the CAs resposible of your certificate.

[Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210) you can find a tutorial on this subject.

Comment: The problem is that I conect to the server written on C. So I cannot export sertificate via browser.

Comment: @Max The fact that the server is written in C has no bearing on your ability to export its certificate. If its certificate isn't signed by a CA it is the server people's problem to get you to trust it. If it's your server, it's your problem, and the answer is to export it from the server and import it into your client's truststore.

Comment: Anyway, you'll need the CAs certificates. If you can't export them via browser, the sever support team should be able to send it to you. Or you can use some tool as openssl to get them.

Comment: @EJP that's what I meant, but better explained. Thanks.